# Enable dark mode by default in Next JS application

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have isDarkMode and well as handleDarkMode functions in my Next JS application

In the Header component, I have a toggle button to allow users to switch from light to dark

```
<ThemeContainer>
            <label className="theme js-theme">
              <span className="theme__icon" onClick={() => handleDarkMode()}>
                <svg className="icon icon-theme-light">
                  <use xlinkHref="#icon-theme-light"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg className="icon icon-theme-dark">
                  <use xlinkHref="#icon-theme-dark"></use>
                </svg>
              </span>
            </label>
</ThemeContainer>
```

However, I would like the dark mode button to be set by default when users visit the website for the first time - any clue how I could implement this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hello Victor! What do you mean with "I would like the dark mode button to be set by default"? Do you mean having light mode enabled by default?

Comment: Hi! I want the dark mode enabled by default - for now, it's the light mode that is enabled by default :) Thanks!

Comment: Hello! can't you just call the handleDarkMode function on document init? (As for the default theme to be set on first visit you can look into local storage)

Comment: Hi Elissi! Thank you for your answer! Well, I don't really know how do to this..any idea? Many thanks...

Comment: @EricQvarnström Sorry, forgot to mention you!

Comment: @Elissi same here :) Glad you can help!

Comment: @Victor do some research first based on the tips you get from the comment section here, and if you still don't understand you can always come back later and ask some more specific questions. Answering your question further now only leads to the community of stack overflow doing your work for you, which doesn't really help you in the long run

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by simply adding the **dark** class on html tag.

```
<Html className="dark">
```

I also tried using **useEffect**, but it did not work, because it execute the callback after the **dom** has already loaded.

Comment: Maybe useLayoutEffect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useEffect hook, with no dependency array so it is executed when the page is loaded, or simply by using the window.onload function, but since you are using react, it is easier to use useEffect:

```
 import {useEffect} from "react"
    
    useEffect(() => {
      handleDarkMode();
    }, []
)
```